# How to calculate difference between two columns on a particular timestamp and apply that value to data in other rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a dataset like this

```
RecTime      NO2_RAW    NO2   Species ReadingDateTime LAQN_NO2
06/6/19 04:00   31.84   80.03   NO2 06/6/19 04:00       38.3
06/6/19 04:15   34.01   84.16   NO2 06/6/19 04:15       39.1
```

I want to calculate the difference between LAQN_NO2 and NO2_RAW everyday at 04:00 and add that value to NO2_RAW values in other rows on that particular day. I have 2 months of data and I want to do this for each day.

So, I want a table like this

```
RecTime  NO2_RAW    NO2 Species  ReadingDateTime    LAQN_NO2  NO2_RAW_Cal
06/6/19 04:00 31.84 80.03 NO2     06/6/19 04:00      38.3     (38.3-31.84)+31.84
```

Note: I have many empty cells of LAQN_NO2 in my table. How will I calculate NO2_RAW_cal and apply this to other rows on a particular day?
Can someone please help?

Comment: What's the  difference between `NO2_RAW_Cal` and `NO2_RAW`?

Comment: I want to match the NO2_RAW data with the LAQN_NO2 at 04:00 everyday. So I wanted to add the difference between these two (LAQN_NO2 - NO2_RAW) to NO2_RAW to calculate NO2_RAW_cal. NO2_RAW_cal will be the calibrated data.